# Babel and hyperref cause pdf form error with ngerman option

Tags: hyperref, babel

I want to test the `Form` environment provided by `hyperref`, especially `\CheckBox` and `\PushButton` and encountered errors in behavior when `babel` is used with the `ngerman` language option.

The purpose of the `\PushButton` is to provide a `activate all` checkboxes at once and uses some `JavaScript` code, I am no expert in `JavaScript` however.

As long as `ngerman` is not used as the language option, the code works as expected, I tested with `Adobe Acrobat DC 11` on Windows 10 and with `PdfStudio Pro 2019` on Linux.

Clicking on the pushbutton with `ngerman` activated does provide nothing, i.e. the `JavaScript` code fails, but I suspect there is a problem with label names needed by `hyperref`.

I use pdflatex with TeXLive 2020 on Linux, last updated this day.

Is there a solution to this problem? I want to keep `babel` since many of my documents rely on `ngerman` and the 'interactive' `Form` would be nice to have in some of my older documents, after changing some other code of course.

The following code is minimal, I think and shows the feature. The included screenshot shows the desired feature, at the moment only achievable by dropping `ngerman` as option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
\begin{Form}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \CheckBox[name=abox]{A} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
    \CheckBox[name=bbox]{B} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
    \CheckBox[name=cbox]{C} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
    \CheckBox[name=dbox]{D} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\bigskip

\PushButton[name=activateall,onclick={%
  this.getField("abox").value="Yes";
  this.getField("bbox").value="Yes";
  this.getField("cbox").value="Yes";
  this.getField("dbox").value="Yes";
}]{Activate all}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: deactivate the shorthand before the pushbottom with \shorthandsoff{"}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Oh, that easy, with `\shorthandoff{"}`? It works, thanks a lot. If you add it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate the shorthand locally:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
\begin{Form}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \CheckBox[name=abox]{A} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
    \CheckBox[name=bbox]{B} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
    \CheckBox[name=cbox]{C} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
    \CheckBox[name=dbox]{D} \tabularnewline    \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\bigskip

\shorthandoff{"}
\PushButton[name=activateall,onclick={%
  this.getField("abox").value="Yes";
  this.getField("bbox").value="Yes";
  this.getField("cbox").value="Yes";
  this.getField("dbox").value="Yes";
}]{Activate all}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```